# cron resource temporarily unavailable

Tags: ubuntu, cron, proxmox

I have a proxmox server with a ubuntu lxc container. cron is not working. I am working this as root:

```
cron -l  
  cron: can't lock /var/run/crond.pid, otherpid may be 21952: Resource temporarily unavailable

ls -l /var/run/crond.pid  
  -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 6 Jul 27 13:45 /var/run/crond.pid

ps -ef  | grep cron  
  root       21952       1  0 13:44 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/cron -f

kill 21952

rm /var/run/crond.pid

apt-get install --reinstall cron

service cron restart

cron -l  
  cron: can't lock /var/run/crond.pid, otherpid may be 21982: Resource temporarily unavailable

ls -l /var/run/crond.pid  
  -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 6 Jul 27 13:45 /var/run/crond.pid
```

Comment: What do you want to accomplish with `cron -l`?

Comment: Do you want `crontab -l` instead? What is the output of `service cron status` and are there any errors in cron log (`grep CRON /var/log/syslog` by default)?

Comment: ups, yes, i wanted to use crontab. problem solved.